# how to extract method from iqueryable and apply to new context

Tags: entity-framework, reflection, dispose

I have a subclassed `ListBox` with the following property:

```
Property Query As Func(Of IEnumerable)
```

this i use all over like this

```
MyListBox.Query=Function() MyDBContext.Products
```

or

```
MyListBox.Query=Function() MyDBContext.Clients.Where(function(x) x.Age>25)
```

etc

I now see that the way I use the  `Query` property all over, never disposes of the MyDBContext, since I'm not using `Using`

so the question is:

Is there a way in my ListBox to grab only the function part of the func (i.e. `.Clients.Where(function(x) x.Age>25)` and apply it to a different dbcontext that i will use and dispose of internally in `MyListBox`?

Thank you very much

Comment: Declare the property type to be `Func<MyDbContext, IEnumerable>` (not sure how it translates to VB, but you get the point)?

Comment: @IvanStoev In VB, it's `Func(Of DbContext, IEnumerable)`.

Comment: There isn't necessarily an `IQueryable` here; the property takes a `Func` which returns an `IEnumerable`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with a "Query" property on a Listbox, is this a custom Listbox extension?  In any case if you want a one-off population of a control using data from the DbContext without leaving the DbContext reference open then:

```
MyListBox.Query=Function() MyDBContext.Clients.Where(function(x) x.Age>25).ToList()
```

should do the trick.

However, if your control is capable of relatively intelligent paging scrolling etc. for handling large data volumes then you'd probably want to build that DbContext reference into your listbox control code, in which case the function signature you'd use would be to identify the DbSet and the Where clause to retrieve its data from. This would likely involve a bit of reflection to pass in the DbSet property name, then re-resolve that against the List's DbContext and then feed it the Where expression. (probably more complicated than you'd need. :) )